# Eclipse is closed automatically in ubuntu14.04

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-adt

#### I tried to solve this issue by add following line at the end of your eclipse.ini file .(eclipse.ini file is located in eclipse folder of eclipse package.)

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

**But Still my Eclipse crashing every 10 to 15 mins.**
 [ I'm new to Ubuntu environment, Guide me to solve issue, help me to go forward. ]

**This is the log I got it from Terminal:**

**androidmachine@android-Satellite-C640:~/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/eclipse$ ./eclipse**

Merged dex A (215 defs/322.4KiB) with dex B (19 defs/42.5KiB). Result is 234 defs/434.9KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (234 defs/434.9KiB) with dex B (13 defs/21.6KiB). Result is 247 defs/574.6KiB. Took 0.2s
Merged dex A (247 defs/574.6KiB) with dex B (22 defs/24.6KiB). Result is 269 defs/811.7KiB. Took 0.1s
Merged dex A (269 defs/811.7KiB) with dex B (232 defs/216.1KiB). Result is 501 defs/1462.3KiB. Took 0.1s
Result compacted from 2920.4KiB to 1112.0KiB to save 1808.4KiB
Merged dex A (501 defs/1462.3KiB) with dex B (414 defs/539.3KiB). Result is 915 defs/1112.0KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (915 defs/1112.0KiB) with dex B (77 defs/97.2KiB). Result is 992 defs/1476.3KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 4889.4KiB to 3689.5KiB to save 1199.8KiB
Merged dex A (992 defs/1476.3KiB) with dex B (2819 defs/2506.6KiB). Result is 3811 defs/3689.5KiB. Took 0.7s
Merged dex A (3811 defs/3689.5KiB) with dex B (185 defs/325.3KiB). Result is 3996 defs/4842.1KiB. Took 0.3s
Result compacted from 6146.2KiB to 4038.2KiB to save 2108.0KiB
Merged dex A (3996 defs/4842.1KiB) with dex B (37 defs/45.3KiB). Result is 4033 defs/4038.2KiB. Took 0.4s
Merged dex A (4033 defs/4038.2KiB) with dex B (628 defs/645.6KiB). Result is 4661 defs/5674.8KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 7381.4KiB to 4804.4KiB to save 2577.1KiB
Merged dex A (4661 defs/5674.8KiB) with dex B (153 defs/155.1KiB). Result is 4814 defs/4804.4KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (216 defs/322.9KiB) with dex B (19 defs/42.5KiB). Result is 235 defs/435.5KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (235 defs/435.5KiB) with dex B (13 defs/21.6KiB). Result is 248 defs/575.4KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (248 defs/575.4KiB) with dex B (22 defs/24.6KiB). Result is 270 defs/812.8KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (270 defs/812.8KiB) with dex B (232 defs/216.1KiB). Result is 502 defs/1464.0KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 2923.2KiB to 1112.4KiB to save 1810.8KiB
Merged dex A (502 defs/1464.0KiB) with dex B (414 defs/539.3KiB). Result is 916 defs/1112.4KiB. Took 0.1s
Merged dex A (916 defs/1112.4KiB) with dex B (77 defs/97.2KiB). Result is 993 defs/1476.9KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 4890.1KiB to 3689.9KiB to save 1200.1KiB
Merged dex A (993 defs/1476.9KiB) with dex B (2819 defs/2506.6KiB). Result is 3812 defs/3689.9KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (3812 defs/3689.9KiB) with dex B (185 defs/325.3KiB). Result is 3997 defs/4842.6KiB. Took 0.1s
Result compacted from 6147.0KiB to 4038.7KiB to save 2108.3KiB
Merged dex A (3997 defs/4842.6KiB) with dex B (37 defs/45.3KiB). Result is 4034 defs/4038.7KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (4034 defs/4038.7KiB) with dex B (628 defs/645.6KiB). Result is 4662 defs/5675.4KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 7382.2KiB to 4804.8KiB to save 2577.4KiB
Merged dex A (4662 defs/5675.4KiB) with dex B (153 defs/155.1KiB). Result is 4815 defs/4804.8KiB. Took 0.4s
Merged dex A (216 defs/323.0KiB) with dex B (19 defs/42.5KiB). Result is 235 defs/435.5KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (235 defs/435.5KiB) with dex B (13 defs/21.6KiB). Result is 248 defs/575.5KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (248 defs/575.5KiB) with dex B (22 defs/24.6KiB). Result is 270 defs/812.9KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (270 defs/812.9KiB) with dex B (232 defs/216.1KiB). Result is 502 defs/1464.1KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 2923.4KiB to 1112.4KiB to save 1811.0KiB
Merged dex A (502 defs/1464.1KiB) with dex B (414 defs/539.3KiB). Result is 916 defs/1112.4KiB. Took 0.1s
Merged dex A (916 defs/1112.4KiB) with dex B (77 defs/97.2KiB). Result is 993 defs/1476.9KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 4890.1KiB to 3690.0KiB to save 1200.1KiB
Merged dex A (993 defs/1476.9KiB) with dex B (2819 defs/2506.6KiB). Result is 3812 defs/3690.0KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (3812 defs/3690.0KiB) with dex B (185 defs/325.3KiB). Result is 3997 defs/4842.7KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 6147.0KiB to 4038.7KiB to save 2108.3KiB
Merged dex A (3997 defs/4842.7KiB) with dex B (37 defs/45.3KiB). Result is 4034 defs/4038.7KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (4034 defs/4038.7KiB) with dex B (628 defs/645.6KiB). Result is 4662 defs/5675.5KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 7382.3KiB to 4804.8KiB to save 2577.4KiB
Merged dex A (4662 defs/5675.5KiB) with dex B (153 defs/155.1KiB). Result is 4815 defs/4804.8KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (216 defs/323.0KiB) with dex B (19 defs/42.5KiB). Result is 235 defs/435.5KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (235 defs/435.5KiB) with dex B (13 defs/21.6KiB). Result is 248 defs/575.5KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (248 defs/575.5KiB) with dex B (22 defs/24.6KiB). Result is 270 defs/812.9KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (270 defs/812.9KiB) with dex B (232 defs/216.1KiB). Result is 502 defs/1464.1KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 2923.4KiB to 1112.4KiB to save 1811.0KiB
Merged dex A (502 defs/1464.1KiB) with dex B (414 defs/539.3KiB). Result is 916 defs/1112.4KiB. Took 0.1s
Merged dex A (916 defs/1112.4KiB) with dex B (77 defs/97.2KiB). Result is 993 defs/1476.9KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 4890.1KiB to 3690.0KiB to save 1200.1KiB
Merged dex A (993 defs/1476.9KiB) with dex B (2819 defs/2506.6KiB). Result is 3812 defs/3690.0KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (3812 defs/3690.0KiB) with dex B (185 defs/325.3KiB). Result is 3997 defs/4842.7KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 6147.0KiB to 4038.7KiB to save 2108.3KiB
Merged dex A (3997 defs/4842.7KiB) with dex B (37 defs/45.3KiB). Result is 4034 defs/4038.7KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (4034 defs/4038.7KiB) with dex B (628 defs/645.6KiB). Result is 4662 defs/5675.5KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 7382.3KiB to 4804.8KiB to save 2577.4KiB
Merged dex A (4662 defs/5675.5KiB) with dex B (153 defs/155.1KiB). Result is 4815 defs/4804.8KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (215 defs/322.5KiB) with dex B (19 defs/42.5KiB). Result is 234 defs/434.9KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (234 defs/434.9KiB) with dex B (13 defs/21.6KiB). Result is 247 defs/574.7KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (247 defs/574.7KiB) with dex B (22 defs/24.6KiB). Result is 269 defs/811.8KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (269 defs/811.8KiB) with dex B (232 defs/216.1KiB). Result is 501 defs/1462.4KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 2920.6KiB to 1112.0KiB to save 1808.6KiB
Merged dex A (501 defs/1462.4KiB) with dex B (414 defs/539.3KiB). Result is 915 defs/1112.0KiB. Took 0.1s
Merged dex A (915 defs/1112.0KiB) with dex B (77 defs/97.2KiB). Result is 992 defs/1476.4KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 4889.4KiB to 3689.5KiB to save 1199.9KiB
Merged dex A (992 defs/1476.4KiB) with dex B (2819 defs/2506.6KiB). Result is 3811 defs/3689.5KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (3811 defs/3689.5KiB) with dex B (185 defs/325.3KiB). Result is 3996 defs/4842.1KiB. Took 0.1s
Result compacted from 6146.3KiB to 4038.3KiB to save 2108.0KiB
Merged dex A (3996 defs/4842.1KiB) with dex B (37 defs/45.3KiB). Result is 4033 defs/4038.3KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (4033 defs/4038.3KiB) with dex B (628 defs/645.6KiB). Result is 4661 defs/5674.9KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 7381.5KiB to 4804.4KiB to save 2577.1KiB
Merged dex A (4661 defs/5674.9KiB) with dex B (153 defs/155.1KiB). Result is 4814 defs/4804.4KiB. Took 0.4s
Merged dex A (215 defs/322.5KiB) with dex B (19 defs/42.5KiB). Result is 234 defs/434.9KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (234 defs/434.9KiB) with dex B (13 defs/21.6KiB). Result is 247 defs/574.7KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (247 defs/574.7KiB) with dex B (22 defs/24.6KiB). Result is 269 defs/811.8KiB. Took 0.0s
Merged dex A (269 defs/811.8KiB) with dex B (232 defs/216.1KiB). Result is 501 defs/1462.4KiB. Took 0.0s
Result compacted from 2920.6KiB to 1112.0KiB to save 1808.6KiB
Merged dex A (501 defs/1462.4KiB) with dex B (414 defs/539.3KiB). Result is 915 defs/1112.0KiB. Took 0.2s
Merged dex A (915 defs/1112.0KiB) with dex B (77 defs/97.2KiB). Result is 992 defs/1476.4KiB. Took 0.1s
Result compacted from 4889.4KiB to 3689.5KiB to save 1199.9KiB
Merged dex A (992 defs/1476.4KiB) with dex B (2819 defs/2506.6KiB). Result is 3811 defs/3689.5KiB. Took 0.4s
Merged dex A (3811 defs/3689.5KiB) with dex B (185 defs/325.3KiB). Result is 3996 defs/4842.1KiB. Took 0.1s
Result compacted from 6146.3KiB to 4038.3KiB to save 2108.0KiB
Merged dex A (3996 defs/4842.1KiB) with dex B (37 defs/45.3KiB). Result is 4033 defs/4038.3KiB. Took 0.3s
Merged dex A (4033 defs/4038.3KiB) with dex B (628 defs/645.6KiB). Result is 4661 defs/5674.9KiB. Took 0.2s
Result compacted from 7381.5KiB to 4804.4KiB to save 2577.1KiB
Merged dex A (4661 defs/5674.9KiB) with dex B (153 defs/155.1KiB). Result is 4814 defs/4804.4KiB. Took 0.3s

Comment: Are you running KDE?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

At the end of `eclipse/configuration/config.ini`

See here for [details](https://askubuntu.com/a/459129/175109)

Comment: I did these changes too. Not yet problem is solved ! still it is happening every 10 mins once.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this. I had the similar problem and got success by following this

```
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382812
```

Comment: Don't just post links. Always give at least an excerpt or the main idea, so people don't need to read huge external pages (and also can use the answer in case the external page goes away).